# Laravel one-to-many update failure problem

Tags: php, laravel

```
class Video extends Model
{
    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, CategoryVideo::class, 'video_id','category_id');
    }
}


DB::beginTransaction();
$video = Video::find($id);
$video->update($data);
// update categorie count
$items = $video->categories()->get(['category_id', 'video_count']);
foreach ($items as $item){
      $item->video_count = Category::where('category_id',$item->category_id)->count();
      $item->save();
      //$item->update(['video_count' => Category::where('category_id',$item->category_id)->count()]);
}
DB::commit();
```

save and update have no effect

Ask for help

I want to find out the associated classification through the video, and update the number of videos under the classification

Comment: What have you tried to deubg the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter in many to many relation is the pivot table model name, not the the pivot model name, so your relation should be like this:

```
 public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_video', 'video_id','category_id');
    }
```

please replace the second parameter  'category_video' by the name of your pivot table.

you also have to select the primary key in categories when you get Category model instance:

```
$items = $video->categories()->get(['id','category_id', 'video_count']);
```

Comment: Modified in your way, but it still doesn't take effect

Comment: category_id Is the primary key in categories table?

Comment: Mine is a relational table, and the primary key id is id

Comment: CREATE TABLE `vod_category_video` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '视频id',
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '分类id',
  `state` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '状态,1:发布,0:不发布',
  `order` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '排序',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vod_category_vod_video_id_category_id_state_order_index` (`video_id`,`category_id`,`state`,`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=107 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: then you have to select the primary key, see my updated code